# Status Bar Style changes from light to black when resuming from multitask

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, statusbar

If I double tap the home button to bring up all the apps that are loaded on my phone and then select my app, the status bar style will be black for a second and then switch to white again.

Comment: I don't understand if there is a question here?

Comment: I need the status bar to stay white the whole time

Comment: and I do not know how to make it stay white when resuming the app from multitasking

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `info.plist` file of your app make sure to add this `Status bar stytle` and `View controller-basedStatus bar appearance`

[image: info.plist file configuration]

I found adding this also helps for the view in question.

```
func navigationController(navigationController: UINavigationController, willShowViewController viewController: UIViewController, animated: Bool) {
        // for some reason, they thought it would be fun to switch the status bar color when this is presented, so we'll change it back.... -.-
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarStyle = .LightContent
}
```

Comment: Did you delete your app from your phone and clean your working directory before building again. UI changes are often cached.

Comment: Yes I just did that and it still does not work sadly

Comment: Nope. I dont understand why it wont work by simply adding those fields in my plist

Comment: Ya probably something you could file under a radar with apple.  But adding that function to my app delegate fixed it for me.